# Why do I have to input a non-integer at then end of the inputs to end the program?

Tags: c++, io, stdin

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, value = 0;

    // read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read
    while (std::cin >> value)
        sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value

    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How does this code know when to finish grabbing input values and display sum? Why does it only end when I input a non-integer value?

Comment: You should properly indent your code if you want people to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop ends when `std::istream& operator>>(int)` evaluates to false. That happens if the stream has hit end of file or has been marked as in error. Entering a floating point number causes the latter to occur.

**Details**:
Every stream includes a bitmask that indicates the status of the stream. The bits in the mask comprise an eof bit, a fail bit, and a bad bit (`std::ios_base::eofbit`, `std::ios_base::failbit`, and `std::ios_base::badbit`). The first is rather obvious: It's set upon hitting EOF. The next two are a bit trickier. `std::ios_base::failbit` is set when an input operation failed to read the expected characters, or when an output operation failed to generate the desired characters. `std::ios_base::badbit` is set when something goes very wrong, e.g., your disk is fried. The conversion from a stream reference to a boolean eventually involves checking that none of these bits is set. The decimal point in a floating point number causes the fail bit to be set, and that in turn causes your loop to end.

Comment: is it `std::stream` or `std::istream`

Comment: Cleaner input style would be to allow the user to enter anything (into a string), parse the string for a number and use the number, and detect some non-numeric entry such as "exit", "quit", "done", "stop", et al, and then quit sanely.  Oh, and why not issue an error when invalid entry is given.

Comment: I don't particularly like the idiom "cin >> variable" because of the one-dimensionality of input treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Because as long as you are typing intergers, the `cin >> value` expression evaluates to true. If you type a non-integer, the expression will fail because you would be trying to put a non-integer into your `value` variable of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`while (std::cin >> value)` will ends when there is no input (ctrl-D or end of stream) or has something bad occurred. Your input of a non-integer gives an error then it terminate the `while`

Answer (score 0):

The line `while (std::cin >> value)` is saying to continue running while `std::cin >> value` is true. Conveniently, since `value` is an `int`, if you enter value which can't be implicitly converted to an `int`, then that expression will return false. Otherwise, it keeps going.